# Ignore semantic versioning in NPM

Tags: npm, npm-install, semantic-versioning

Is there a way to ignore semantic versioning check in NPM? Today I spent quite a lot of time to figure out why the build server is failing today, just to discover that when your project has version which does not match semantic versioning `npm install` would wrte a warning and exit silently. This is of course absolutely ridiculius, because if it failed with a non 0 exit code at least it would be clear where is the problem.

Is there a way to disable this check, because, honestly, I don't care if npm likes my version or not, I need my dependencies installed.

Comment: Just wondering, why wouldn't you want to use semantic versioning?

Comment: @Nathan there is a historical reason why in my company we need to have some extra periods for versioning. But it is not important, I'm not saying that semantic versioning is bad, I'm just saying that there are always exceptions, and it doesn't make sense to stop installing other packages because of that

Comment: Agree with @Uko, for simplicity, major version is enough